# Docker container registers Enter Key on terminal continuously

Tags: bash, docker, go

I am building an image with Dockerfile. I am pulling latest Ubuntu and golang images.

After importing all the directories and building the executable with go build inside the image, I want to run the executable. For that reason, I tried using either `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, so that the executable runs when the container starts.

The issue is that when I do that and I am running the container in either attached or detached mode, it keeps registering the `Enter Key` repeatedly all the time (and CPU usage goes crazy). I can understand this because my script waits for a key to be registered and then some input to terminate, but since the Enter key is registered immediately again, it prints a message and then the same loop happens again.

When I build my image without executing (no `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`) the binary, I then run the container (the binary is still built inside the image) with a bash terminal and I execute the binary and all goes normal as it should, without any `Enter Key` registering all the time.

Any ideas why this might be happening???

Brief description of my Dockerfile:

```
# Import Images
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM golang:1.10

# Open ports
EXPORT ...

# Copy dependencies to GOPATH in docker file
COPY github.com/user/dependencies /go/src/github.com/user/dependencies
...

# Set working directory and build executable
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/app-folder
RUN go build

# Run the binary (or not)
CMD ["app_name"]
-----OR-----
CMD ["./app_name"]
-----OR-----
ENTRYPOINT app_name
-----OR-----
ENTRYPOINT /go/src/github.com/user/app-folder/app_name
```

In the end, I tried all these, one at a time, I just included them like this for display. The result was always the same. The result in the terminal is:

```
...
Are you sure you want to exit? y/n
running. press enter to stop.

Are you sure you want to exit? y/n
running. press enter to stop.
...
```

The go script is as follows:

```
// running flag is set to True and then it scans for a newline
    for running {
        fmt.Println("running. press enter to stop.")
        fmt.Scanln()
        fmt.Println("Are you sure you want to exit? y/n")
        if models.ConfirmUserAction() {
            running = false
            close(models.DbBuffer)
        }
    }
```

and the models package that includes the `ConfirmUserAction` function:

```
//ConfirmUserAction waits (blocks) for user input, returns true if input was Y/y, else false.
func ConfirmUserAction() bool {
    var confirm string
    fmt.Scanln(&confirm)
    if confirm == "y" || confirm == "Y" {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Can you provide Dockerfile and/or script?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example (see http://sscce.org/) of the code used to read the input.

Comment: With "run in attached mode", you mean with the `-it` argument for "interactive"?

Comment: @daniu yes. Basically, if I do not start the app in the container using CMD etc, I run with: sudo docker run --network="host" -i -t <name> /bin/bash, and I start the binary and all is good. If I use CMD, I am either running the container with: docker run --network="host" <name> or docker run -d --network="host" <name> and then  attach to the container. In the last two cases, the Enter key is always being registered.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I will add my script's scan for key code above. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage Thanks a lot for the input. I added the code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to bypass this issue by creating a shell script inside the container, which then runs the executable (maybe a bit hacky way, but the Enter Key is not registering any more all the time).

So now, instead of running the executable at the `ENTRYPOINT` on my Dockerfile, I am running the shell script at the `ENTRYPOINT` which simply includes something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 1;

echo "Starting Metrics Server..."
./metrics_server
```

The metrics_server is my compiled executable and I am setting the working directory `WORKDIR`, inside my Dockerfile to be were the executable and the shell script are.

Something worth mentioning about this, is that I already have imported the Ubuntu image in my Dockerfile (`FROM ubuntu:18.04`), as I need it anyways. I am saying this because it might not work without it (not entirely sure, I did not try it).